# how to get date from ajax calender in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

The following  is my .aspx code for ajax calender

```
 <ajax:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" TargetControlID="TextBox1" runat="server">
            </ajax:CalendarExtender>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
           </td><td>
```

and aspx.cs code is

```
string date = Request.Form[TextBox1.UniqueID];
        comp.DATETIME = Convert.ToDateTime(date);
```

string value could not converted to datetime. how to convert this into datetime

Answer (score 0):

```
<td>
Date Received From
    </td>
    <td >
    <asp:TextBox ID="TxtSearchDate_Received_From" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <a  runat="server" id="HrefDateReceivedFrom"></a>
    <asp:CalendarExtender Format="dd-MM-yyyy" ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="TxtSearchDate_Received_From"
PopupButtonID="HrefDateReceivedFrom" Enabled="True" />
    </td>
```

Then use txtsearchDate_received_from control on the server side. This is a good practice as the use can view selected date in text box control.

Let me know if it works for you

Answer (score 0):

Why haven't you tried just getting the `.Text` property value from the server control, like this?

```
string date = this.TextBox1.Text;
```

Then you can do your conversion to `DateTime`, like this:

```
comp.DATETIME = Convert.ToDateTime(date);
```

Comment: I already try this. but string value could not convert into datetime

Comment: What is the value in `TextBox1.Text`?